# Pitchypoy rigify issue

Tags: rigify

Using a character rigged with Pitchypoy Rigify in different scenes.
Can't understand why when opening certain scenes the "rig layers" normally visible in the N panel disappear.

My "auto run scripts" in pref users is ON.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Appending the rigged object to different scenes doesn't automatically include/run the `rig_ui.py` script. The script can then be located in the original `.blend` file's `/Text` folder.

You can also keep a local copy of the script by generating a new Rigify rig in an empty scene and saving it. Just be sure to change the `rig_id` in the script to match the rig you wish to generate a UI for before you run it... like this:

[image: Rigify rig id]